# Is there any possibility that i search on the table name users and then specifically on the column of user table name role in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
var users = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('userName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
    url: '/Api/Users/?Role=1&query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
}

});

$('#supervisor').typeahead({    
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true
},`
```

> Here is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply by adding a query parameters in the query